# Array as criteria in Excels COUNTIFS function, mixing AND and OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been googling this for a while and can´t seem to get it to work. I use Excel 2010 and want to count rows on a mix of AND and OR operators.

What I want to do is something like this

```
COUNTIFS($A:$A,"string1" , $B:$B,"string2" , $C:$C,{"stringA","stringB","stringC"})
```

This means mixing both AND and OR operator in the COUNTIFS function. Col A and col B must match the string criteria but col C must only match one of the values in the array given as criteria. Match on colA AND colB AND on one array value in col C.

A different approach would be to create one COUNTIFS function for each value in the array like

```
COUNTIFS($A:$A,"string1" , $B:$B,"string2" , $C:$C,"stringA") + COUNTIFS($A:$A,"string1" , $B:$B,"string2" , $C:$C,"stringB") + COUNTIFS($A:$A,"string1" , $B:$B,"string2" , $C:$C,"stringC")
```

This however is a lot of duplicate code and that bugs me! The logic solution would be to pass an array as criteria for column C. Also my array contains more then three values...

When I do this in Excel the formula is accepted and a few rows are counted but the results are way to low. It is not the result I´m expecting.

Any Excel-Pro out there that can tell me if this is possible? It would save me a lot of work!
Thanks!

Comment: Please note that the duplicate you refer to does not have the correct answer marked as a solution. This question does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($A:$A,"string1",$B:$B,"string2",$C:$C,{"stringA","stringB","stringC"}))
```

you can also use a similar array construction with sumproduct

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A:$A="string1")*($B:$B="string2")*($C:$C={"stringA","stringB,"stringC"}))
```

Comment: Oh hey, I didn't know that countifs can accept array conditions. Nice +1

Comment: Why does that work? =) What does the COUNTIFS return that SUM can count on? An array? As I wrote in my original post COUNTIFS with an array as criteria returns values but they are to low. Do you know what is returned by the COUNTIFS the SUM uses? Thanks!

Comment: it returns an array of 3 values-one for each combination of the array criteria with the other two criteria

Comment: ahh thats so clever! Thanks i'll try it out and see which method is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, well, 'or' does make things longer. See a [related question](https://superuser.com/q/590185/219090). I guess you could use `=SUMPRODUCT()` but still have it a bit long. Being an array function though, you'll have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A:$A="string1")+0,($B:$B="string2")+0,((($C:$C="stringA")+($C:$C="stringB")+($C:$C="stringC"))>0)+0)`

**Disclaimer**: I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: Thanks, it kind of works. It does deliver the corrects amounts but it is slower then a snail on the sticky side of duct-tape. A series of COUNTIFS with repetitive code is much faster. It surprises me a little that Excel lacks this ability to mix logical operators and send arrays as criteria. But the important thing is that it can be solved. I give you correct answer but recommend others to user multiple COUNTIFS instead. Cheers Jerry!