# COUNTIF with an array formula referencing dynamic cells

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to use a COUNTIF with a dynamic array as the criteria.

I have changing names in cells D1, E1, and F1, so when I update the values in those cells the COUNTIF returns a different sum based on the what names are used as the criteria.

```
=COUNTIF(Col!A:A, "Test", Col!B:B, {D1, E1, F1})
```

I'm using an array because sometimes the values in D1, E1, or F1, maybe blank, so I need COUNTIF to only count the values which are switching in and out of the array evaluating B:B.

Example data with answers below:

```
ColA ColB

Test Rob
Foo  Jim
Test Ted
Bar  Rob
Test Rob
Test Jim
Foo  Ted
Test Jim
Test Ted


=COUNTIF(Col!A:A, "Test", Col!B:B, {"Rob", "Jim", "Ted"})
Answer: 6

=COUNTIF(Col!A:A, "Test", Col!B:B, {"", "", "Ted"})
Answer: 2

=COUNTIF(Col!A:A, "Test", Col!B:B, {"", "Jim", "Ted"})
Answer: 4
```

I've looked here, but I'm not writing this with VBA code

[Excel COUNT() vs COUNTIF() with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734503/excel-count-vs-countif-with-arrays)

And I've tried this method, but it won't let me put cell references into the array without popping an error. I can put in strings, but I need my array to have values pop in and out.

[Array as criteria in Excels COUNTIFS function, mixing AND and OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169525/array-as-criteria-in-excels-countifs-function-mixing-and-and-or)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it in SUM() and enter it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Col!A:A, "Test", Col!B:B, D1:F1))
```

The array needs to be contiguous and one row or column.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've lost 2 hours looking for this answer and finally, just before giving up, I found it !